# Simpleinjector DI issue with Formbuildercontroller

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am getting error when i try to create "new  blank form" through Sitecore forms.

The error is :

> Exception message: No registration for type FormBuilderController could be found and an implicit registration could not be made. The constructor of type FormBuilderController contains the parameter with name 'formRenderingContext' and type IFormRenderingContext that is not registered. Please ensure IFormRenderingContext is registered, or change the constructor of FormBuilderController.
>      at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
>      at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceForRootType(Type serviceType)
>      at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
>      at Carestream.PublicSite.Extension.DI.SimpleInjectorControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in C:\Project\Carestream\Develop_0611\Develop\src\CarestreamPublicSite\Carestream.Extension\DI\SimpleInjectorControllerFactory.cs:line 19
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
>
> The constructor of type FormBuilderController contains the parameter with name 'formRenderingContext' and type IFormRenderingContext that is not registered. Please ensure IFormRenderingContext is registered, or change the constructor of FormBuilderController.
>      at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowParameterTypeMustBeRegistered(InjectionTargetInfo target)
>      at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.GetInstanceProducer(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer, Boolean throwOnFailure)
>      at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.GetInstanceProducerFor(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
>      at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(ConstructorInfo constructor)
>      at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression()
>      at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression()
>      at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>      at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildInstanceCreator()
>      at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()
>      at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()

In our application, we are using simpleinjector DI

**SimpleinjectorControllerfactory.cs**

```
public class SimpleInjectorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private Container _container;

    public SimpleInjectorControllerFactory(Container container)
    {
        this._container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)this._container.GetInstance(controllerType);
    }
}
```

**SimpleInjectorConfig.cs**

```
public class SimpleInjector : IPackage
{
    public SimpleInjector()
    {
    }

    public void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior = new DefaultFirstConstructorBehavior();
        container.Register<ISitecoreService>(() => new SitecoreContext());
        container.Register<ISitecoreContext>(() => new SitecoreContext());
        container.Register<ISiteContextAdapter, SiteContextAdapter>();
        container.Register<IGlassHtml, CarestreamGlassHtml>();
        container.Register<IFormRenderingContext, FormRenderingContext>();
        container.Register<ISitecoreLog, SitecoreLog>();
        container.Register<IControllerSitecoreContext, ControllerSitecoreContext>();
        container.Register<ICacheLogic, CacheLogic>();
        container.Register<ICacheRepositoryLogic, MemCacheRepositoryLogic>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<IDateTimeLogic, DateTimeLogic>();
        container.Register<IMetaTagsLogic, MetaTagsLogic>();
        container.Register<IScriptsLogic, ScriptsLogic>();
        container.Register<ISiteSettingsLogic, SiteSettingsLogic>();
        container.Register<INavigationLogic, NavigationLogic>();
        container.Register<IProduct, Product>();
        container.Register<ILookupDataLogic, LookupDataLogic>();
        container.Register<INewsTicker, NewsTicker>();
        container.Register<INewsAndEvents, NewsAndEvents>();
        container.Register<ILeftMenu, LeftMenu>();
        container.Register<IDISUser, DISUserLogin>();
        RegisterGlassMapper(container);
        RegisterRepositories(container);
        container.Register<ISocialMedia, SocialMedia>();
        container.Register<IDealerWarrantyRegistration, DealerWarrantyRegistration>();
        container.Register<IIncludesCSSBusiness, IncludesCSSBusiness>();
        container.Register<IIncludesJSBusiness, IncludesJSBusiness>();
    }

    private void RegisterRepositories(Container container)
    {
        var helper = new InjectorHelper();
        var types = helper.GetInjectorTypes();
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("SimpleInjector", types.Count);
        //TODO Below line to be removed only for testing purpose
        container.RegisterCollection<IJsonHelper>(helper.GetTypes<IJsonHelper>(types));
        container.RegisterCollection<INavigationRepository>(helper.GetTypes<INavigationRepository>(types));
    }

    private void RegisterGlassMapper(Container container)
    {
        string str = ".DataAccess";
        IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies =
            from assem in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            where assem.FullName.IndexOf(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            select assem;
        Type glassmapType = typeof(IGlassMap);
        var typeList = new List<Type>();
        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            if (typeList.Count == 0)
                typeList = assembly.GetTypes().Where<Type>((item => glassmapType.IsAssignableFrom(item))).ToList<Type>();
            else
                typeList.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes().Where<Type>((item => glassmapType.IsAssignableFrom(item))).ToList<Type>());
        }
        container.RegisterCollection<IGlassMap>(typeList);
    }
}
```

**SimpleInjector.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
           xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <initialize>
      <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc"
               set:type="Carestream.PublicSite.Extension.DI.InitializeSimpleInjectorControllerFactory, Carestream.PublicSite.Extension" patch:before="*[@type='Carestream.PublicSite.Web.App_Start.GlassMapperSc, Carestream.PublicSite.Web']" />
    </initialize>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**InitializeSimpleInjectorControllerFactory.cs**

```
public class InitializeSimpleInjectorControllerFactory
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        this.SetControllerFactory(args);
    }

    protected virtual void SetControllerFactory(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        InstanceManager containerManager = new InstanceManager();
        SetContainerOptions(containerManager.Container);
        PackageExtensions.RegisterPackages(containerManager.Container, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where<Assembly>((a => a.FullName.StartsWith("XXX.PublicSite."))));
        System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new SitecoreControllerFactory(new SimpleInjectorControllerFactory(containerManager.Container)));
    }

    protected virtual void SetContainerOptions(Container container)
    {
        if (container == null)
            return;

        container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new ImportAttributePropertySelectionBehavior();
    }
}
```

- **ContainerManager.cs**

  public class ContainerManager
  {
      private static readonly Container container = new Container();

  ```
  public Container Container
  {
      get
      {
          return ContainerManager.container;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Have you seen this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16527/sitecore-9-forms-simpleinjector-conflicting-with-formbuildercontroller. I had the same issue when going to 9. Not with Forms, but other things because of Simple Injector. Switching to Microsoft fixed the issue. I suggest doing that as you will run into other issues.

Comment: Hi @RReilley : Thank you. Will look into Microsoft DI.